# Using Tox(tox.chat) with Tor

Tags: torsocks, bittorrent, chat

I know there's "Tor Messenger", but it's centralized, not peer to peer. So I am using ["qTox"](https://github.com/tux3/qtox) with Tor, which use [Tox](https://tox.chat/) protocol (again, not "tor" but "tox").

The question is, does Tor welcome P2P traffic?
IIRC I read about the blog which Tor Project yelling "Stop using BitTorrent over Tor".

Answer (score 1):

Tox is pretty centralized and it's pretty terrible in a lot of ways, but those points aside peer-to-peer is fine. The problem with bittorrent is that it is high-volume peer-to-peer to a large number of peers. There is no problem with peer-to-peer in general.

If you want to use peer-to-peer, "decentralized" messaging over Tor, consider that a solution already exists: [Ricochet](https://ricochet.im)

And it's not subject to all the [NIH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) junk in Tox. Seriously just read their "onion routing" code, it is utterly horrific. It picks circuits by doing: `node[i] = nodes[ rand() % sizeof(nodes) ];` which is wrong in so many ways it hurts.